# How do I breed a Sapphire Dragon in Dragonvale?

Tags: dragonvale

It's September, and the Sapphire Dragon is the gemstone dragon of the month. What is the best combination to breed it, and what is the incubation time?

Comment: Takes 30 hours because there is 30 days in September. It's that way for all the months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the Dragonvale wiki](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Sapphire_Dragon), to get a Sapphire Dragon you must breed a Rain Dragon with a Mountain Dragon. The incubation time is 30 hours for the regular Breeding Cave/Epic Breeding Island. If you have the upgrade to either breeding location the time is reduced to 24 hours. The Sapphire Dragon is only available in September, and requires that you are level 14 to breed it.

Answer (score 2):

Scorch and rust, I think, but mine is still breeding.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sapphire dragon. I breed it by plant and air hybrid.